# The handle could not be opened during redirection of handle 1

Tags: .net, command-line, cmd, io, io-redirection

I'm using this code for saving a backup of my application database before exiting my application (I'm also calling this function manually on main form's closed event):

```
Private Sub Exit_Application() Handles btnExitApplication.Click, tsmiMainExit.Click
    Me.dump.Export(options.auto_backup_path + "\ON_EXIT " + Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm.bak"))
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

and here is the `Export()` function defined in my dumping class:

```
Public Class MysqlDump

    Public mysql_path As String
    Public db_name As String

    Private proc As New Process

    Sub New(ByVal mysql_dir As String, ByVal dbname As String)
        Me.mysql_path = mysql_dir
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\cmd.exe"
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Me.mysql_path + "\bin"
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Me.db_name = dbname
    End Sub

    Public Function Export(ByVal file_name As String) As Boolean
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/c mysqldump {0} | gzip > ""{1}""", db_name, file_name)
        proc.Start()
        Dim sdd As String = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        proc.WaitForExit()
        If proc.ExitCode <> 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Failed status:" + proc.ExitCode.ToString() + vbNewLine + "Error Info:" + sdd)
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

And all the codes above are running fine when running/debugging project from visual studio (with debug/x86 configs) but when I try to run compiled application executable file from it's own directory it throws out this exception every time closing application, failing to save backup of my database before exit:

> System.Exception: Failed status:255
>
> Error Info:The handle could not be opened during redirection of handle 1.

#### Update

If I set `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = FALSE` and comment `= proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` the error disappears, but I want to be able to redirect command line errors and show them as exception message in my application.

Comment: From your first sentence, it sounds like this is being called more than once - perhaps _at the same time_.  Since `MysqlDump` uses the same `Process` for every invocation, you could well be getting a timing issue where it's trying to run and redirect the same handle at the same time from two different places in your code.  Do you _need_ to call it more than once?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I also checked this by directly calling export() function from dump class by handling button click event and find out the error is not related to use same proccess twoice, or application exiting at same time, I'm quite sure about it's relation to StandardError (mentioned in update) or OS / simulations of proccess from x86 or x64 which may cause crash of StandardError redirection but I don't know very much about streams and IO details.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around net for some good examples of StandardError redirection I found a working example and compared it to my codes so I found the point is that I should not just set `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True` option but also **I should set `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True` as well** and after adding this line of code now I'm able to redirect errors to my application successfully and show them as new exception.

But yet **I don't know the reason WHY should I do this?!**